# "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" when calling cv.glm function

Tags: r, logistic-regression, cv.glm

I have been trying to evaluate the performance of a logistic regression model by cross validation, which I've already done before. I have at my disposal a dataset of over 200 000 rows for 12 variables and am trying to predict the variable TARGET with the explanatory variables 1 through 11.

After splitting my original dataset in a training dataset and a testing one, I've fit several logistic regression model (optimised regarding AIC, BIC ..) which gave me 2 models : mod1.1 and mod2.1. Here is the code associated with those opperations :

```
reglog_max = glm(data = train,formula = TARGET~.,family = "binomial") # maximal logistic regression
regback_aic = step(reglog_max,direction = "backward",k=2,trace = 0) # AIC
regback_bic = step(reglog_max,direction = "backward",k=log(nrow(train)),trace = 0) # BIC

mod1 = eval(regback_aic$call)
mod2 = eval(regback_bic$call)
```

I could evaluate the performance of this one-shot training just fine for each model but things got trickier when i tried to evaluate these performance with K-fold cross validation.

```
library(boot)

cost=function(r, pi){
  sum((pi>0.2) & (r==1))/sum(pi>0.2)
}

cv.glm(dftest,mod2.1,cost,K=10)
```

> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthlonger object length is not a multiple of shorter object length$call
> cv.glm(data = dftest, glmfit = mod2.1, cost = cost, K = 10)
>
> $K
> [1] 10
>
> $delta
> [1] NA NA

I don't understand because 1- this code worked just fine in another notebook on another dataset and 2 -I don't get why the observed responses and the fitted responses are of different length.
Also, there are no NA in the dftest dataset.

Could you help me figure it out?
Thanks for your help !